# Taylor series for (exp(x) - exp(-x))/(2*x)

Tags: matlab, infinite-loop, taylor-series

I've been asked to write a function that calculates the Taylor series for (exp(x) - exp(-x))/(2*x) until the absolute error is smaller than the eps of the machine.

```
function k = tayser(xo)
f = @(x) (exp(x) - exp(-x))/(2*x);
abserror = 1;
sum = 1;
n=2;
while abserror > eps
    sum = sum + (xo^n)/(factorial(n+1));
    n=n+2;
    abserror = abs(sum-f(xo));
    disp(abserror);
end 
k=sum;
```

My issue is that the abserror never goes below the eps of the machine which results to an infinite loop.

Comment: I think the condition should be "until the absolute error is _comparable_ to the eps of the machine". If you manage to have an error below eps it will be by chance. eps is too low a threshold. You should probably use something like 10*eps as the asbolute error threshold

Comment: What `xo` do you use? I've tried a few, and don't get an infinite loop.

Comment: Thank you very much for your instant reply @LuisMendo. I tried some logical cases using the eps of the machine and 0 and I ended up that what I am asked is "until the absolute error is 0" {since 0<eps returns 1-true). I changed my while's condition to "while abserror~=0", but still getting an infinite loop though.

Comment: @ViG Thanks for your instant reply. I am trying for o=10^−13, xo=10^−14,xo=10^−15,xo=10^−16 and xo=0.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is expression you're using. For small numbers `exp(x)` and `exp(-x)` are approximately equal, so `exp(x)-exp(-x)` is close to zero and definitely below 1. Since you start with 1 and only add positive numbers, you'll never reach the function value.

Rewriting the expression as

```
f = @(x) sinh(x)/x;
```

will work, because it's more stable for these small values.

You can also see this by plotting both functions:

```
x = -1e-14:1e-18:1e-14;
plot(x,(exp(x) - exp(-x))./(2*x),x,sinh(x)./x)
legend('(exp(x) - exp(-x))/(2*x)','sinh(x)/x')
```

gives

[image]

Comment: Wow! Thank you very much! This way it totally works! You're awesome! :D